# How to use unique key as foreign key

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I have an N:N relationship between 2 tables, `users` and `titles`. These tables link using a third table `purchases` which should have the `id` of each of the others table. The problem is that for the `titles` I do not require the `title_id` on the `purchases` table, but a different column named `item_id` which is `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` on the `titles` table.

Currently I have the following migration, but it is not working. I might be missing something:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :purchases, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :title, foreign_key: 'item_id'
      t.belongs_to :user, :null => false
    end
  end
end
```

How can I get my `purchases` table to reference the `titles` table using that `item_id` key on the `titles` table rather than `title_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :purchases, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :item_id
      t.integer :user_id, :null => false
    end
  end
end
```

In your models:

```
# app/models/title.rb
class Title < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users,
    class_name: "User",
    foreign_key: "item_id",
    association_foreign_key: "user_id",
    join_table: "purchases"
  # ...
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :titles,
    class_name: "Title",
    foreign_key: "user_id",
    association_foreign_key: "item_id",
    join_table: "purchases"
  # ...
end
```

Don't forger add indexes to migration if its need.